# NSUserAutomatorTask variables array/list values cannot be parsed by Automator actions

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, workflow, automator

I am using `NSUserAutomatorTask` to launch an Automator workflow from a macOS app.

I'm passing in variables via the `variables` property:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserautomatortask/1418099-variables

Inside the Automator workflow I will then use `Get Value of Variable` actions to grab the variables that were set on the `NSUserAutomatorTask` and pass the variables to subsequent Automator actions:

[image: Get Value of Variable]

---

Code looks like this: (simplified; I also [check that the variables exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507620/setting-nsuserautomatortask-variables-without-requiring-automator-workflows-to-d) in the workflow)

```
let workflow = try! NSUserAutomatorTask(url: url)
workflow.variables = [
    "singleFilePath": "/image1.png",
    "multipleFilePaths": ["/image1.png", "/image2.png"],
]
workflow.execute(withInput: nil)
```

I'm able to print out the variable values in an alert via an `Ask for Confirmation` action:

[image: variable string values.]

The `String` variable's value is a simple string: `/image1.png`

The `[String]` array variable's value is wrapped in parentheses and each item is quoted:

```
(
  "/image1.png",
  "/image2.png"
)
```

---

I now run the pictured Automator workflow that first gets a variable's value and then attempts to open those Finder items.

The `singleFilePath` var works. It's passed on to the Open Finder Items action, and that file is opened by the default application.

Passing `multipleFilePaths` in the same manner does not work. No files are opened. Automator displays the error:

> The action "Open Finder Items" was not supplied with the required data.

---

The action is "Open Finder Item**s**", so there must be some way to pass multiple file paths to this action.

My questions and solutions in order of preference are:

1. Why is the default variable array/list format not working when passed to the subsequent action? Is there any way to pass or parse the array variable in a compatible format?
2. Can we use a *single* `Run AppleScript` action to reformat the array variable into a format that can be passed to subsequent Automator actions? (I'd like to continue to chain Automator actions rather than run pure AppleScript).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576397/how-do-i-get-these-results-in-separate-automator-variables

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147427/automator-adding-unwanted-line-breaks

Comment: running automator workflows from the command line: https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/invoking-automator-workflows-command-line/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Open Finder Items` actions *can* open an array of items if used in a normal non-variables workflow. And it's seemingly in the exact same format.

As a control to test this, rather than the variable, I'm using the `Get Specified Finder Items` action.

I then use a `View Results` action to inspect what is sent to `Open Finder Items`.

The results are seemingly exactly the same as when I parse the variable:

```
(
  "/image1.png",
  "/image2.png"
)
```

[image: Get Specified Finder Items]

This workflow *does* correctly run the final action and open the files.

So `Open Finder Items` should work with the data I'm setting in the variable. I'm unsure why the variable data cannot be opened but manually-picked files can.

---

I opened a DTS ticket for this issue and received the following response:

> I’m sorry to say the engineers working on this have confirmed that yes, it’s a bug, and no, there isn’t a workaround for sandboxed apps. They’ve also noted this isn’t a regression in behavior from previous releases.